# ipv6 socket connect refused and errno 111 use c language on debian10

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I wrote a IPv6 remote connection TCP socket server and client code, but I don't know why the connection is always rejected? The socket() , bind(), listen() , accept() functions of the server and the socket() functions of the client did not fail, and I pinged the 6 server from the client successfully.

I used other code, I run UDP socket client on the TCP socket server system, and run UDP socket server  On the TCP socket client system. The UDP socket server and client can receive and send data. Shouldn't there be a problem with the firewall?

1, a part code of server.c

```
int gw_server_socket_init(int *server_fd, struct sockaddr_in6 *serv_addr, unsigned int tcp_port)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int fd;
    unsigned int addrPort = tcp_port; 

    fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if( -1 == fd)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    memset_s(serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6), 0x0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    serv_addr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serv_addr->sin6_port = htons(addrPort);
    serv_addr->sin6_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    serv_addr->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    
    ret = bind(fd, serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    if(0 != ret )
    {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }    
   
    
    char buf[40] = {0};
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, (char *)(&serv_addr->sin6_addr), buf, 40);

    
    ret = listen(fd, 1);
    if(0 != ret )
    {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }    
    *server_fd = fd;
    return VOS_OK;
}

int gw_server_socket_accept(int fd, struct sockaddr_in6 * serv_addr )
{
    int sockson_fd = 0;
    sockson_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
    if(-1 == sockson_fd )
    {
        return -1;
    }    
    return sockson_fd;
}


int main()
{
      unsigned int ret;
      struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr = {0};
      unsigned int tcp_port = 7770;
      ...
      ...
      ret = gw_server_socket_init(&server_fd, &serv_addr, tcp_port);
      if (ret == -1)
      {
          return;
      }
      son_server_fd = gw_server_socket_accept(server_fd, &serv_addr);
      ...
      ...
      ...
}
```

2, a part of client.c

```
#define VOICEFILE_SENSOR_PORT       7770
void SendDataFunction(void)
{
    unsigned intsockfdSend;
    struct sockaddr_in6 dest;      // IPv6
    unsigned inti = 0;
    unsigned intlength = 0;

    sockfdSend = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfdSend < 0)
    {
        printf("Send vocie file socket created fail\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    else
   {
        printf("Send vocie file socket created success\n");
        bzero(&dest, sizeof(dest));
        dest.sin6_family = AF_INET6;     
        dest.sin6_port = htons(VOICEFILE_SENSOR_PORT);
        //dest.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("veth1@if7");
        //dest.sin6_addr.s6_addr = inet_addr("fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031");
        if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fc00::2a4:1ff:fe15:7031", &dest.sin6_addr) != 1)
        {
            printf("inet_pton failed!\n");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        

        if (connect(sockfdSend, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest)) == -1)
        {
            printf("vocie Connect to dest failed , errno = %d\n", errno);
            perror("connect");
           close(sockfdSend);
        }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Any firewall in place?

Comment: @kaylum I test udp socket on the same environment. udp socket is normal, There should be no firewall.

Comment: A firewall _could_ block TCP but not UDP or ICMP.

Comment: what is SERVER_IPV6 for, is it the server's address? I notice it's a different address than the client is connecting to.

Comment: @ user253751 SERVER_IPV6 not used, server address is in6addr_any.